# How to Configure the Registry's Shell Command to Display the Desktop

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, windows-registry

Background: I have been intrigued by the idea of by-passing Windows 8's Metro UI by adjusting the Registry's Shell setting.

Location: HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
Shell Explorer (Default)

I have experimented with appending /root /e and /Select.  Upon booting many of my test options swerve the Metro UI, but none provide the usual Windows 8 desktop complete with Taskbar.

What I get is an explorer which I can 'Root' and 'Select', but there is no sign of the Taskbar.

Question: Is my objective possible using the shell setting and explorer switches?  
Note: I don't want a 3rd party product.

For perfection I would like to be able to press WinKey and get out of the traditional desktop into the Metro UI.

Comment: You can try to use *Scheduled Tasks*: create a task that starts a desktop application when you logon. Notepad or Calculator can be used for testing. You can configure the task to stop the running task after a minute or so. (If it's successful, a simple desktop app can be written which starts, shows no windows, and then exits by itself.)

Comment: The article [3 Way To Boot Straight to Desktop in Windows 8](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2012/08/3-way-to-book-straight-to-desktop-in-windows-8/) might be of interest to you.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov I tried the Task Scheduler.  Notepad launched, but it did not cause a switch from the Metro UI to the Desktop.  As soon as switched manually, there was notepad, but it would not change to desktop automatically.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Karan That is a good answer, it works.

Comment: Good to know! So did you end up using the Show Desktop icon or the executable?

Comment: @Karan I found only the .exe works.  Incidentally, I am experiencing a strange effect, I miss the Metro-style UI!